# How can I see who is in a group behind an email alias in Googlemail?

Tags: google-apps-email

For the first time, I'm working for a company that thinks Google's functionality-light web applications where everything runs in Chrome are preferable to Microsoft's tried-and-tested Office suite that runs natively on the desktop. (You can probably tell I'm not impressed so far!)

Anyway, in Exchange/Outlook, if I add a group as a recipient of an email, then I can examine the group to see who's in it, expand it to see the individual names if I want to remove some, etc.

In Gmail it seems that groups appear only as an email alias, a bit like a discussion group or marketing list online. There's no way (I can find) to know ahead of time whom you're sending to, or to take some people out of the distribution if it's not appropriate for them - I need to type/select each recipient individually if I want to do this.

Am I wrong? Is there actually a way of achieving this?